# Joomla | Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS in /.../behavior.php on line 17

Tags: php, joomla

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS in /homepages/1/d160385903/htdocs/etri/libraries/joomla/html/html/behavior.php on line 17
```

In this script:

```
<?php
/**
* @version      $Id: behavior.php 18130 2010-07-14 11:21:35Z louis $
* @package      Joomla.Framework
* @subpackage   HTML
* @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2008 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
* @license      GNU/GPL, see LICENSE.php
*
* Joomla! is free software. This version may have been modified pursuant
* to the GNU General Public License, and as distributed it includes or
* is derivative of works licensed under the GNU General Public License or
* other free or open source software licenses.
* See COPYRIGHT.php for copyright notices and details.
*/

defined('JPATH_BASE') or die();

/**
 * JHTML helper class for loading JavaScript behaviors into the document head.  This version is
 * designed to load MooTools version 1.2 plus the 1.1 compatibility layer.
 *
 * @package     Joomla.Framework
 * @subpackage  HTML
 *
 * @since       1.5.19
 * @static
 */
class JHTMLBehavior
{
/**
 * Method to load the mootools framework and compatibility layer into the document head.  If the
 * optional debug flag is set then a uncompressed version of the files will be loaded.
 *
 * @param   boolean  $debug  True to enable debugging mode.  If no value is set the value  will
 *                           be taken from the application configuration settings.
 *
 * @return  void
 *
 * @since   1.5.19
 * @static
 */
function mootools($debug = null)
{
    // Check to see if it has already been loaded.
    static $loaded;
    if (!empty($loaded)) {
        return;
    }

    // If no debugging value is set, use the setting from  the application configuration.
    if ($debug === null) {
        $debug = JFactory::getConfig()->getValue('config.debug');
    }

    /*
     * Note: Konqueror browser check.
     *  - If they fix thier issue with compressed javascript we can remove this.
     */
    $kcheck = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'konqueror') : null;

    // If the debugging flag is set or the browser is Konqueror use the uncompressed file.
    if ($debug || $kcheck) {
        JHTML::script('mootools-uncompressed.js', 'plugins/system/mtupgrade/', false);
    }
    else {
        JHTML::script('mootools.js', 'plugins/system/mtupgrade/', false);
    }
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

-M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method chaining is not available in php 4.

It is available in PHP 5.x

Thats why `$debug = JFactory::getConfig()->getValue('config.debug');` is working in PHP 5.x but not in PHP 4.x

[This](http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1163-php5-method-chaining.html) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Once I close the method and class statements, I don't receive  any parse error with PHP 5.3.3. Which version of PHP are you using? And what version of the Joomla installation?

Comment: Joomla 1.5.22 & PHP 4. I think some "wrong" data may be handed over by the mysql-db, causing that error.

Comment: If I change my PHP interpreter to PHP 4.3 I get a parse error at this line:  `$debug = JFactory::getConfig()->getValue('config.debug');`. I change back to PHP 5.2 or 5.3 and the error disappears.

Comment: In PHP 4.x you can't have methods returning objects, and so the chaining there gives a parsing error.